# Finding the percent of a number

Tags: c++, c, performance, algorithm

I'd like to create a function that returns the percentage of a number as an int (in this case 10%, so it would return 10% of the int passed in), for example if you passed 76, it would return 8.
Essentially it is like the function below, but I'm thinking that there must be a better way to do it.

```
int percent(int y){
    int x;
    if(y >= 95)
        return 10;
    else if(y >= 85)
        return 9;
    else if(y >= 75)
        return 8;
    ...
}
```

Comment: `return (y+5)/10;`?

Comment: are you allowed to use floating point calculations? I am wondering if this is a homework.

Comment: I see variable `y` is passed in.  What is variable `x` used for?

Comment: Do you need function for 10% or for n percent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int percent(int y){
   return (y + 5) / 10;
}
```

You have integer division there, so it would work for rounding!

Comment: To call this method `percent` is quite a stretch. It's more of a rounded divide by ten.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean for it to be read into that much..it was just an example so people could understand what I was asking for. "return (y+5)/10;" is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
int percent(int y){
    return (y + 5) / 10;
}
```

But I would give the function a different name because I don't think this is the normal meaning of percent.

Answer (score 1):

This for any percentage, not only 10.

```
    int CountPercentage(int input, int percentage)
    {
        long long x = static_cast<long long>(input) * static_cast<long long>(percentage);
        long long ret = x / 100;

        if (x - ret * 100 >= 50)
        ++ret;
        return static_cast<int>(ret);
    }
```

Also if you can use WinAPI you can solve it this way:

```
int CountPercentage(int input, int percentage)
{
    return MulDiv(input, percentage, 100);
}
```

Comment: I think that `MulDiv` will compensate for overflows, but your `CountPercentage` won't.

Comment: @MooingDuck thanks for showing my mistake. temporary result during `MulDiv` is 64-bit wide so it calculates always right...

Comment: Uh, now that I look at your code, your rounding is done wrong.  You... might want to look into that. (Hint: `ret*100` is _always_ `>50` unless `ret==0`.)

Comment: Also just noticed that `long long x = input * percentage;` still overflows, because it does the overflow, _then_ converts to 64 bits

Comment: @MooingDuck I have to admit, that didn't think about that, made a fix, but now code looks not so good.

Answer (score 0):

If input is always not negative you can use this:

```
int percent(int y){
   return (y + 5) / 10;
}
```

Otherwise you need this:

```
int percent(int y){
    return (y >= 0 ? (y + 5) : (y - 5)) / 10;
}
```